# How to integrate pytorch lightning profiler with tensorboard?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I know we can use torch profiler with tensorboard using something like this:

```
with torch.profiler.profile(
        schedule=torch.profiler.schedule(wait=1, warmup=1, active=3, repeat=2),
        on_trace_ready=torch.profiler.tensorboard_trace_handler('./log/resnet18'),
        record_shapes=True,
        with_stack=True
) as prof:
    for step, batch_data in enumerate(train_loader):
        if step >= (1 + 1 + 3) * 2:
            break
        train(batch_data)
        prof.step()  # Need to call this at the end of each step to notify profiler of steps' boundary.
```

It works perfectly with pytorch, but the problem is I have to use pytorch lightning and if I put this in my training step, it just doesn't create the log file nor does it create an entry for profiler. All I get is `lightning_logs` which isn't the profiler output. I couldn't find anything in the docs about lightning_profiler and tensorboard so does anyone have any idea?
Here's what my training function looks like:

```
def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        
        with torch.profiler.profile(
        activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU],
        schedule=torch.profiler.schedule(
            wait=1,
            warmup=1,
            active=2,
            repeat=1),
        with_stack=True,
        on_trace_ready=torch.profiler.tensorboard_trace_handler('./logs'),
        ) as profiler:
        
            x, y = train_batch
            x = x.float()
          
            logits = self.forward(x) 
            
            loss = self.loss_fn(logits, y)
            profiler.step()
        return loss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use raw `torch.profiler` at all. There is a [whole page](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.0/advanced/profiler.html) in Lightning Docs dedicated to Profiling ..

.. and its as easy as [passing a trainer flag](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.0/advanced/profiler.html#pytorch-profiling) called `profiler` like

```
# other profilers are "simple", "advanced" etc
trainer = pl.Trainer(profiler="pytorch")
```

Also, set `TensorBoardLogger` as your preferred logger as you normally do

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(profiler="pytorch", logger=TensorBoardLogger(..))
```

Comment: But I want to use the torch profiler so that I can trace every operation being performed. I tried using `trainer = pl.Trainer(profiler="pytorch", logger=TensorBoardLogger(..))` but the profiler doesn't show up on tensorboard

Comment: @Madara my guess is that you haven't installed `torch_tb_profiler` as [mentioned here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_profiler_tutorial.html#run-the-profiler)

Comment: Did it work @Madara ?

Comment: Yes, it did @ayandas :)